# How to Find A Path of Length X Between Two Nodes in A Weighted (Undirected) Graph

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, dictionary, routes

Given a graph, how can I find a path of length X between two nodes in the graph. The path should ideally visit an edge no more than once.

Comment: Are you allowed to visit nodes multiple times?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to visit a node repeatedly.

Comment: Also, do you want length *exactly* X, or length *at most* X?

Comment: A length exactly X or within a threshold of X.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a modified BFS algorithm. Once you find the first path from A to B, you have the minimum length of said path, so if X is less than this value, you already know there are now paths.

If X is great than this value, proceed like this: Go over the path from A to B you just found and annotate each node with it's distance to B.

Then, continue your BFS search until you cover the whole graph.

Each time your search arrives to an already used node, you can see if it leads to B, and if it does, how far away from it it is. This allows you to know the length of the new path you just found, and you can compare to X.

Again, annotate each node in this path with it's distance to B. You should allow for a node to be annotated more than once, and once you hit a used node that leads to B, compare using all of the annotated values of said node.

Whenever you hit a path of length greater than X, you can stop searching.